# Redis Multiple Key Set Counts

Tags: count, redis

So I add keys to my Redis implementation for wallpaper view counts like this...
(the values are there for demonstration purposes but the overall format is the same)

```
SADD wallpapers:100:2015-12-31 "127.0.0.1"
SADD wallpapers:100:2016-01-01 "127.0.0.1"
SADD wallpapers:100:2016-01-01 "192.168.1.1"
SADD wallpapers:100:2016-01-02 "127.0.0.1"
```

So that should add the IP's in the associated sets. So my question is, do they allow some sort of pattern based counts?

```
SCARD wallpapers:100:2016:01-01
```

For example the above command would return "2", as there are two IPs stored in the set, but is there a way to run something like the below command to get all counts for all the dates?

```
SCARD wallpapers:100:*
```

Comment: Not sure what do you want, a value per key, or all keys combined into one value (cardinality of the super-set)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's easier than you've ever thought: store less specific sets to be able to get what you want.

For example, if you need `wallpapers:100:*` it means that you just need a *set* called `wallpapers:100` where you store unique IP addresses there.

That is, whenever you add an IP addresses to one of  specific sets (i.e. *daily sets*), also add it to the global *set* for a given wallpaper identifier.

Redis is like working with a manual index. Index your data in a way you can efficiently use it. That's all! This means that data redundancy is a good approach.

Comment: This technique requires up to 2 times more RAM. Depending on the data volume, this can be prohibitive.

Comment: Also, more expensive writes (2 instead of 1)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Maybe 2x RAM isn't that expensive... If it uses 1GB it'll use 2GB... Nowadays 2GB is cheap.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev In the other hand, who knows if OP is using Redis as live data and the app layer is removing data from Redis to some definitive archive or even removing the data forever...

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Am I mistaken if I understand that both reads and writes are very cheap in Redis?

Comment: Cheap, but not free.

Answer (score 0):

```
EVAL "local total = 0 for _, key in ipairs(redis.call('keys', ARGV[1])) do total = total + redis.call('scard', key) end return total" 0 wallpapers:100:*
```

This command returns you the total number of elements in keys `wallpapers:100:*`.

If you want total number of unique values from all keys combined,

```
EVAL "return redis.call('SUNIONSTORE', 'wallpapers:temp', unpack(redis.call('keys', ARGV[1])))" 0 wallpapers:100:*
```

This will return the number of unique values from all keys combined and also creates a key `wallpapers:temp`

You can delete this key later `del wallpapers:temp`

I used [SUNIONSTORE](http://redis.io/commands/sunionstore) for the second command.

Refer [EVAL](http://redis.io/commands/eval).